# Adding strings to propositions lemma

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

In a book about mathematical logic I am currently reading, there's the following lemma:

Let $\phi$ be a proposition, w a finite string. Then:
If the string $\phi w$ is a proposition, w must be empty, so that $\phi w=\phi$

I don't see why that should be the case, what about $\phi=(a\land b)$ and $w=\lor(b\land c)$, then w is not empty and $\phi w= (a\land b)\lor(b\land c)$ is a proposion?

Comment: See H.D. Ebbinghaus, [Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=4sbSBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA16), page 16.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has to do with the precise details of the formal definition of "proposition" in the system in question. In formal  logic I'm surprised they're not talking about well formed formulas instead.

Since you don't give the details of the definition in force it's impossible to give a definitive answer to your question. But one possibility is this, just to give an idea of what the answer might be: It happens sometimes that wffs are defined by saying that a propositional variable is a wff, and if $a$ and $b$ are wffs then $(a\land c)$, etc, are wffs. With that definition your $(a\land b)\lor(b\land c)$ would not be a wff, because the outer parentheses are missing.

Comment: Sometimes? Isn't that *everytime* but we choose to abandon the outer parentheses as a notational abuse?

Comment: That's the only way I've seen the definition stated. But I haven't seen every treatment of the subject. For example one could say instead that if $a$ and $b$ are wffs then $(a)\land(b)$ is a wff...

Comment: @GitGud No... ? Not to even start with Polish notation, there's no reason we can't *formally* describe those "notational abuses" so they aren't notational abuses. I agree that defining syntax fully parenthesized is a common approach, but it definitely isn't "every time". Many syntax descriptions (admittedly, not usually in introductions) abuse notation by not even bothering with the parentheses in the definition. You are supposed to know from conventions and perhaps a few brief sentences, where and how to place parentheses.

Comment: @DerekElkins Fine. If you want to argue with what are clear outliers, do. I agree that universal quantification is incorrect.

Comment: @GitGud Personally, I find the focus on parsing concerns in some introductions to logic misguided, though I understand the mindset that leads one to it. Logic requires such concerns no more (or less) than high school algebra, say. Defining formulas as special finite strings is a mistake.